# How do you integrate $\int_0^1 yn(1-y)^{n-1} \, dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to figure out how to evaluate this integral: 
$$\int_0^1 yn(1-y)^{n-1} \, dy = \frac{1}{n+1}$$ where n is an integer greater than 1.  I just don't know where to begin.  Can you help point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: If you're interested, see also [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: @Lucian That's wonderful, thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Lucian. Didn't you consider $\int_0^1 y^n(1-y)^{n-1} \, dy$ instead ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, I took *n* to be a constant which can be factored outside of the integral sign. But the connection to the beta function holds either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use substitution with $z=1-y$.

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts
$$\int_0^1 y n(1-y)^{n-1} dy = -y (1-y)^n\Big|_0^1 +\int_0^1 (1-y)^n dy $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

$y=-z \implies dy =-dz$

$\dfrac{d}{dz}{\left((1+z)^n\right)}=n(1+z)^{n-1}$

$\therefore\displaystyle\int yn(1-y)^{n-1}\ dy\\=\displaystyle\int zn(1+z)^{n-1}\ dz\\=z\displaystyle\int n(1+z)^{n-1}\ dz-\displaystyle\int\left(\displaystyle\int n(1+z)^{n-1}\ dz\right)dz$